# DOMPDF with laravel - cannot load images in html file

Tags: php, html, laravel, render, dompdf

I'm trying to generate pdf file with laravel and dompdf lib. Here is my code from controller:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $pdf = new Dompdf();
    $html = Storage::disk('local')->get('public/pdf/template.html');
    $pdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $pdf->render();
    $filename = "Hi!";
    return $pdf->stream($filename, ["Attachment" => false]);
}
```

And in `template.html` I got some html, somewhere there I got images like this:

`<img src="img/logo.png" alt="BTS">`

But dompdf cant write this image: `Image not found or type unknown`. My file system is:

`.pdf
...img
......here is images
...template.html
...*some_fonts_files*`

But at the same time, fonts are loading fine. What should I do to render images in template.html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that for dompdf you need to pass a properly accessable url rather than relative paths.

Try 
`<img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png')}}" alt="BTS">`

Alternatively if asset doesn't work please try 
`<img src="{{ public_path('img/logo.png')}}" alt="BTS">`

Also please note that asset uses the public directory as the base_url to calculate the 'asset' from.

Comment: If you `dd(asset('img/logo.png'));` what does that show?

Comment: This URL works fine from browser, but from dompdf it does not work

Comment: perhaps instead try `<img src="{{ public_path('img/logo.png')}}" alt="BTS">`

Comment: Does it work if you use an external image - something like https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a

Comment: oh, no, it works fine, my bad! Thanks :) Update your answer, then I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: In my case, it wasn't working because I tried to access a remote URL and in the config, it defaults to not allow remote accessing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Me too i struggled for the same error for 3 days. Also when i tried tricks mentioned above, none of them worked too. But when i changed the image file to **.jpg** file(extension) everything worked well.

```
<img src="{{ public_path('img/logo.jpg') }}" >
```

- Laravel version: 5.8.38
- PHP version: 7.3
- barryvdh/laravel-dompdf version: 0.8.6

Comment: thanks its work,..
last version (0.8.5) i uses asset() function its work but in version 0.8.6 it not work. @Angelwise why the asset() function is not work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the image path as the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag.

Suppose you have the path to the location of your image in a variable:
`$img =  asset($imgen);`

Yust echo it out like this:
`<img src="@php echo $img @endphp">`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a need to set the protocol and add an additional option:

```
    $pdf->setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled' => true]);
    $pdf->getDomPDF()->setProtocol($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```

Or:

`$pdf->setProtocol($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

After this `src="/storage/myimage.png"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all tips!! The only one solution that works for me is:

```
header {
            background-image: url("https://example.org/logo.jpg");
        }
```

and

```
$pdf->setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled' => true]);
$pdf->getDomPDF()->setProtocol($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```